# Maven results on Run and Tests Run are not same

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, cucumber-jvm, maven-surefire-plugin, cucumber-java

I' trying to test 4 scenarios in a feature using the <sub>mvn clean test</sub> and all the tests are running as expected but the results shows as below

**Maven Result**

```
[INFO]   Run 1: PASS
[ERROR]   Run 2: MainRunner.runScenario » NoSuchIdentifiableElement Element fileExplorerButton ...
[INFO]   Run 3: PASS
[ERROR]   Run 4: MainRunner.runScenario » NoSuchIdentifiableElement Element fileExplorerButton ...
[INFO]
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[ERROR] There are test failures.
```

> Runner class

@CucumberOptions(
features = "classpath:cucumber-features/someTest.feature",      glue = {             "automatedtest.tests.steps",
"autotest.arch.steps" },
plugin = {
"pretty",
"html:target/cucumber-html-report/",
"json:target/cucumber-json-report/report.json",            "io.qameta.allure.cucumber6jvm.AllureCucumber6Jvm"
}
)
public class MainRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {}

I dont understand why is there a mismatch.

**PARENT POM**

```
<dependencyManagement>    
<dependencies>        
<dependency>           
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>           
 <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>           
 <version>${spring.version}</version>           
 <type>pom</type>           
 <scope>import</scope>      
 </dependency> 
 </dependencies></dependencyManagement>
 <build>    
 <pluginManagement>        
 <plugins>            
 <plugin>                
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>                
 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>              
 <configuration>                  
 <source>1.8</source>                    
 <target>1.8</target>               
 </configuration>          
 </plugin>            
 <plugin>                
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>            
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>         
 <version>3.0.0-M3</version>    
 <configuration>    
 <includes>    
 <include>**/MainRunner.class</include>    
 </includes>      
 <printSummary>true</printSummary>  
 </configuration>  
 </plugin> 
 </plugins>  
 </pluginManagement>
 </build>
```

**POM under src/test/**

```
<plugin>   
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId> 
 <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
 <configuration>  
 <includes>    
 <include>**/MainRunner.class</include>   
 </includes> 
 </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

I tried to add

```
<forkCount>, <printSummary>,
```

Comment: First it would help to post the full pom file as well as full error / Log output of your problem.. and not excerpts... furhtermore I would ask why have you configured `<include>**/MainRunner.class</include>` apart from that can you explain where the mismatch is because I don't see or can not understand where the difference should be??? Also using an old version of maven-surefire-plugin ... formatting the code improves readability... and why kind of testing framework do you use???

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello @khmarbaise thanks for your reply. It's a BDD with testng framework. In BDD framework we have a runner class which helps in running the test cases and generating the report and it's called as MainRunner class that's why we have used <include>**/MainRunner.class</include> so when we run the test cases using Maven it executes the syntax from this MainRunner class     . The main issue that I face is I see Run1,2,3,4 but the finals result says Tests 1 instead of 4( please refer the Maven result code)